# Can trusted data layer in data lake replace data warehouse?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse, azure-data-lake, data-lake

in modern data architecture, data lakes are divided into multiple layers, data is store in raw form in landing zone then curated and stored with summarizations in trusted/application layers. And I believe we can even do reporting out of trusted data in data lakes. IF that's the case I am unable to think of a logic which could justify existence of data warehouse ? Or is it that trusted data itself is Datawarehouse ? Or trusted data is it more like just aggregating the data and not doing proper modelling, hence still we need data warehouse.?

Can someone please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I believe that the conventional wisdom is that they are complementary architectures, often coexisting in the same ecosystem.  Data lakes generally retain data in its raw form, use schema on read, and are available to read and consume readily.  By contrast, data warehouses typically involve modeling and transformation, with schema on write,  and have a respective latency associated with that data preparation for use.  There’s much more than a comment field here can retain, and I’m sure philosophical debate will ensue 

Comment: Years ago there were both conceptual and technology platform differences between the two terms.  You would need to secure and manage separate tech platforms for each. With the rise of Big Data technologies like Snowflake, the difference is now mostly conceptual. As Snowflake can handle both. 

A data lake is a vast pool of raw data, the purpose for which is not yet defined. A data warehouse is a repository for structured, filtered data that has already been processed for a specific purpose. ELT patterns will have you land data in a lake and then transform as needed into a warehouse.

Comment: Again, this could be a whole Ted Talk, but getting down to brass tacks, the simple question is “could you?” and “should you?”, with the answer of course being “it depends”.  Data virtualization was a hot topic for a couple of years, where all the data was left where it resided, and tools were used to dynamically consolidate and aggregate into a consumable layer.  Everything has a tipping point where a threshold is breached and these solutions expose a critical limitation or are non-performant.

Answer (score 0):

Data lakes originally referred only to the RAW layer. What you are describing is the standard data warehouse layered architecture. I think it is just semantics. If you have the data you need to support the typical data warehouse data use cases such as reporting in the curated and stored summarizations then you don't need another layer. If that layer isn't supporting some data use cases you can either add to that layer or create another layer and call whichever one you want a data warehouse.